# JACK error starting server using FireWire drivers

Tags: jack, firewire

I've been trying to setup an Edirol FA-66 audio interface in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, so that I can record sound coming from two microphones conected to it. The interface is connected to my computer using a FireWire cable. Thanks in advance for your interest and help!

I followed [this FireWire digital audio tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FireWire/DigitalAudio) (I skipped the *Set IRQ Priorities* section, I'm not interested in realtime), after installing Ffado, JACK and QjackCtl, but I get an error I cannot solve.

When I start QjackCtl (with root privileges), apply the settings described in the *Start Jack* section of the above tutorial and click the Start button, I get an [error window and another after I close the first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8saF.png).

Also, there are these errors in the *Messages* window of QjackCtl.

```
18:43:18.581 ALSA connection change.
18:43:18.605 D-BUS: Service is available (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
18:43:18.617 ALSA connection graph change.
18:43:23.877 D-BUS: JACK server could not be started. Sorry
Mon Aug 12 18:43:21 2013: Starting jack server...
Mon Aug 12 18:43:21 2013: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Mon Aug 12 18:43:23 2013: [1m[31mERROR: firewire ERR: FFADO: Error creating virtual device[0m
Mon Aug 12 18:43:23 2013: [1m[31mERROR: Cannot attach audio driver[0m
Mon Aug 12 18:43:23 2013: [1m[31mERROR: JackServer::Open() failed with -1[0m
Mon Aug 12 18:43:23 2013: [1m[31mERROR: Failed to open server[0m
Mon Aug 12 18:43:23 2013: Saving settings to "/home/casir/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
18:43:30.507 Could not connect to JACK server as client. - Overall operation failed. - Unable to connect to server. Please check the messages window for more info.
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

---

First, I know the FireWire board is working correctly, because I can get video from two FireWire cameras connected to the same board.

Second, I know the Edirol audio interface is being recognized, because when I run the command `sudo ffado-test ListDevices`, it produces the following output:

```
=== 1394 PORT 0 ===
Node id GUID VendorId ModelId Vendor - Model
0 0x000a47010f069020 0x00000A47 0x00000000 -
1 0x000a47010f06901f 0x00000A47 0x00000000 -
2 0x001106000000d9ff 0x00001106 0x00000000 Linux Firewire -
3 0x0040ab0000c33a09 0x000040AB 0x00010049 EDIROL - EDIROL FA-66
```

Third, I modified the */etc/pulse/client.conf* to contain the line `autospawn = no`, killed the Pulseaudio process, verified that it was not running anymore and restarted QjackCtl. I still got the same error windows and messages.

Fourth, this is the `sudo ffado-diag` output. I'm not really sure of what some of these things mean, but it seems to me that every necessary library is installed and was found.

```
FFADO diagnostic utility 2.999.0-
============================
(C) 2008 Pieter Palmers
    2009-2010 Arnold Krille


=== CHECK ===
 Base system...
  kernel version............ 3.2.0-51-generic
  old 1394 stack present.... False
  old 1394 stack loaded..... False
  old 1394 stack active..... False
  new 1394 stack present.... True
  new 1394 stack loaded..... True
  new 1394 stack active..... True
  /dev/raw1394 node present. False
 Prerequisites (dynamic at run-time)...
   gcc ............... gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
   g++ ............... g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
   PyQt4 (by pyuic4) . sh: 1: pyuic4: not found
   jackd ............. Home directory /home/casir not ours.
     path ............ /usr/bin/jackd
     flags ........... Package jack was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `jack.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'jack' found
   libraw1394 ........ 2.0.5
     flags ........... -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lraw1394  
   libavc1394 ........ 0.5.3
     flags ........... -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lavc1394 -lrom1394 -lraw1394  
   libiec61883 ....... 1.2.0
     flags ........... -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -liec61883 -lraw1394  
   libxml++-2.6 ...... 2.34.1
     flags ........... -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libxml++-2.6 -I/usr/lib/libxml++-2.6/include  -lxml++-2.6 -lxml2 -lglibmm-2.4 -lgobject-2.0 -lsigc-2.0 -lglib-2.0  
   dbus-1 ............ 1.4.18
     flags ........... -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include  -ldbus-1 -lpthread -lrt  
 Prerequisites (static at compile-time)...
   gcc ............... gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.2-14ubuntu2) 4.6.2
   g++ ............... g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.2-14ubuntu2) 4.6.2
   PyQt4 (by pyuic4) . Python User Interface Compiler 4.9.1 for Qt version 4.8.0
   jackd ............. sh: 1: jackd: not found
     path ............
     flags ........... Package jack was not found in the pkg-config search path.
   libraw1394 ........ 2.0.7
     flags ...........  -lraw1394  
   libavc1394 ........ Package libavc1394 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
     flags ........... Package libavc1394 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
   libiec61883 ....... 1.2.0
     flags ...........  -liec61883 -lraw1394  
   libxml++-2.6 ...... 2.34.1
     flags ........... -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libxml++-2.6 -I/usr/lib/libxml++-2.6/include  -lxml++-2.6 -lxml2 -lglibmm-2.4 -lgobject-2.0 -lsigc-2.0 -lglib-2.0  
   dbus-1 ............ 1.4.16
     flags ........... -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include  -ldbus-1 -lpthread -lrt  
 Hardware...
   Host controllers:
0c:07.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller [1106:3044] (rev 46) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
        Subsystem: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller [1106:3044]
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping+ SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 32 (8000ns max), Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 21
        Region 0: Memory at d3101000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Region 1: I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
        Kernel modules: firewire-ohci

   CPU info:
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            15
Model:                 6
Stepping:              5
CPU MHz:               3391.369
BogoMIPS:              6783.08
L1d cache:             16K
L2 cache:              2048K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1
 Configuration...
  IRQ information
Hardware Interrupts:
--------------------
 IRQ    0: PID:  None, count:           [53, 53], Sched None (priority None), drivers: ['timer']
 IRQ    1: PID:  None, count:             [3, 3], Sched None (priority None), drivers: ['i8042']
 IRQ    6: PID:  None, count:             [3, 3], Sched None (priority None), drivers: ['floppy']
 IRQ    8: PID:  None, count:             [1, 1], Sched None (priority None), drivers: ['rtc0']
 IRQ    9: PID:  None, count:             [0, 0], Sched None (priority None), drivers: ['acpi']
 IRQ   12: PID:  None, count:             [5, 5], Sched None (priority None), drivers: ['i8042']
 IRQ   14: PID:  None, count:     [30347, 30347], Sched None (priority None), drivers: ['ata_piix']
 IRQ   15: PID:  None, count:       [3567, 3567], Sched None (priority None), drivers: ['ata_piix']
 IRQ   16: PID:  None, count:       [1565, 1565], Sched None (priority None), drivers: ['nvidia']
 IRQ   18: PID:  None, count:       [1754, 1754], Sched None (priority None), drivers: ['ehci_hcd:usb1', 'uhci_hcd:usb4']
 IRQ   20: PID:  None, count:             [0, 0], Sched None (priority None), drivers: ['uhci_hcd:usb3']
 IRQ   21: PID:  None, count:       [1185, 1185], Sched None (priority None), drivers: ['uhci_hcd:usb7', 'firewire_ohci']
 IRQ   22: PID:  None, count:         [429, 429], Sched None (priority None), drivers: ['ata_piix', 'uhci_hcd:usb6']
 IRQ   23: PID:  None, count:       [2184, 2184], Sched None (priority None), drivers: ['ehci_hcd:usb2', 'uhci_hcd:usb5']
 IRQ   43: PID:  None, count:         [194, 194], Sched None (priority None), drivers: ['snd_hda_intel']
 IRQ   44: PID:  None, count:     [19415, 19415], Sched None (priority None), drivers: ['eth0']

Software Interrupts:
--------------------


=== REPORT ===
FireWire kernel drivers:

The new FireWire kernel stack is loaded.
This is still kind of experimental. If you encounter problems, please also check
with the old stack.
```

---

If you're still reading after this wall of text, thank you again! Don't hesitate in asking for information I might have overlooked, I will provide it as soon as I can. Thanks for your help!

---

**Edit:** I guess there is something wrong with the ffado drivers, as I get the following error messages when I run `sudo ffado-dbus-server`:

```
-----------------------------------------------
FFADO Control DBUS service
Part of the FFADO project -- www.ffado.org
Version: 2.999.0-
(C) 2008, Pieter Palmers
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
-----------------------------------------------

 Discovering devices...
07562463157: Error (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 750] doFcpTransaction: FCP transaction didn't succeed in 2 tries
07562463194: Warning (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 725] transactionBlock: FCP transaction failed
07562463203: Error (bebob_avdevice.cpp)[  96] probe: Number of channels command failed
07562466270: Error (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 750] doFcpTransaction: FCP transaction didn't succeed in 2 tries
07562466279: Warning (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 725] transactionBlock: FCP transaction failed
07562469318: Error (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 750] doFcpTransaction: FCP transaction didn't succeed in 2 tries
07562469326: Warning (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 725] transactionBlock: FCP transaction failed
07562469339: Error (avc_avdevice.cpp)[  89] probe: Subunit info command failed
07562521750: Error (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 750] doFcpTransaction: FCP transaction didn't succeed in 2 tries
07562521770: Warning (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 725] transactionBlock: FCP transaction failed
07562521774: Error (bebob_avdevice.cpp)[  96] probe: Number of channels command failed
07562524807: Error (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 750] doFcpTransaction: FCP transaction didn't succeed in 2 tries
07562524816: Warning (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 725] transactionBlock: FCP transaction failed
07562527850: Error (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 750] doFcpTransaction: FCP transaction didn't succeed in 2 tries
07562527858: Warning (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 725] transactionBlock: FCP transaction failed
07562527868: Error (avc_avdevice.cpp)[  89] probe: Subunit info command failed
07562994197: Error (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 750] doFcpTransaction: FCP transaction didn't succeed in 2 tries
07562994222: Warning (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 725] transactionBlock: FCP transaction failed
07562994228: Error (bebob_avdevice.cpp)[ 560] getConfigurationIdSampleRate: Stream format command failed
07563403974: Error (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 750] doFcpTransaction: FCP transaction didn't succeed in 2 tries
07563403987: Warning (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 725] transactionBlock: FCP transaction failed
07563403999: Error (bebob_avdevice.cpp)[ 597] getConfigurationIdNumberOfChannel: Number of channels command failed
07563813654: Error (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 750] doFcpTransaction: FCP transaction didn't succeed in 2 tries
07563813673: Warning (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 725] transactionBlock: FCP transaction failed
07563813678: Error (bebob_avdevice.cpp)[ 597] getConfigurationIdNumberOfChannel: Number of channels command failed
07564222639: Error (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 750] doFcpTransaction: FCP transaction didn't succeed in 2 tries
07564222651: Warning (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 725] transactionBlock: FCP transaction failed
07564222663: Error (bebob_avdevice.cpp)[ 629] getConfigurationIdSyncMode: Signal source command failed
07564631256: Error (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 750] doFcpTransaction: FCP transaction didn't succeed in 2 tries
07564631276: Warning (ieee1394service.cpp)[ 725] transactionBlock: FCP transaction failed
07564631283: Error (avc_unit.cpp)[ 250] enumerateSubUnits: Subunit info command failed
07564631298: Error (avc_unit.cpp)[ 177] discover: Could not enumarate sub units
07564631303: Error (bebob_avdevice.cpp)[ 192] discover: Could not discover unit
07564631312: Error (devicemanager.cpp)[ 632] discover: could not discover device
DBUS service running
press ctrl-c to stop it & exit
```

---

Thanks again for your time!